# How could I show the data from mysql to a modal where it I could update it also?

Tags: python, django, modal-dialog

I am trying to show the information/data from mysql to a Modal and on same time.

I can also update those data if possible.

Code from `models.py`

```
class User(models.Model):
   login_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
   user_id = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
   employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
   password = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
   user_type = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)

class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'user'
```

Comment: can you add more details. what have you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand you are fairly new in Django .

First thing is have you written any View for that purpose ? If yes then mentioned in question if not then write a view.

If you want to pull data from db then you can do using below code in your view.

```
def some_view_name(request):
    context = {}
    if request.methond == "GET":
        context['usr_obj'] = User.objects.get(login_id= login_id) # or may be  user object 
    if request.method == "POST":
         usr_obj = User.objects.get(login_id= login_id) # or may be  user object 
         usr_obj.employee = 'update with new employee'
         usr_obj.save()

    render ('temrplate_name.html',context)
```

Howevere you need html where you can display the database value and update the same. Please follow djangobook it has step by step process to do this.